# Regex Password Validation, OR operation

Tags: regex

I need to validate a password with these rules:

1. 7 characters
2. Must contain at least one letter
3. Must contain at least one number OR Special Character;

Below regex follows AND operation,

```
 ^(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[#?!@$%^&*-]).{7,}$
```

Here how to perform OR operation in 3rd rule.

Comment: Most ORing can be done with `( | )` which is called alternation. It the string matches left OR right side, it will pass. That being said, alternation typically makes the regex much longer because it accounts for many cases at the same tim

Comment: `{OFF}` I don't understand but why can I not choose a password I really want to? why does everyone forces to use their own password-policy?

Comment: @skamazin : Can you please edit my regex.

Comment: Put up some sample passwords and say which are valid and invalid. That'll help a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this regex will work:

```
^(?=.*?[a-z])((?=.*?[0-9])|(?=.*?[#?!@$%^&*-])).{7,}$
```

But it's hard to tell without some test data

**[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/uC8pG8/2)**

Comment: it would be better if you put `[\W]` instead of special characters.

Comment: Probably not as that could include characters the OP doesn't want. Note the differences: [\W](http://regex101.com/r/nZ8hY1/1) and [#?!@$%^&*-](http://regex101.com/r/lS5uT1/1)

Comment: @skamazin It works... But if the user satisfies this criteria, then he can enter special characters like `;` as well. How can this be prevented?

Comment: @tastro Use a black list. ie `[^;<any character you want to disallow>]{7,}$` instead of `.{7,}$` at the end of the regex

Comment: @skamazin thanks. Is it possible to satisfy both criteria? 1. criteria: don't allow anything but `a-zA-Z0-9!#%˙` for example and 2. criteria: there have to be at least one lower-case letter, one upper-case letter, one number and one special character (!, # or %)? If yes... Could you provide an example please?

Comment: @skamazin Could you please explain what ?=.* does? I know that a? allows an a or no a at all. Just don't know what the question mark (?) does when you put an equals (=) behind it.

Comment: @skamazin thanks. 1. Is the `?` behind `.*` even necessary? 2. Does g means that multiple matches are returned or that all the sub-patters `sub-pattern is everything inside ()` much be matched?

Comment: `.*?` makes the matching **[lazy](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html)**, which may not be necessary in this case, but it's normally good practice. the `g` flag means `global` so that it can return multiple matches instead of stopping after the first. Depending on your implementation of the regex (iterating line-by-line through a file, or reading the entire file as one long string) you may or may not the `g` flag.

Comment: @skamazin thank you for the explanation. I have opened a new question, so that we won't spam the comment section here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25411819/regex-regular-expression-for-password-validation